# CSS3 Transform Animation

Tags: html, css

My CSS3 animation doesn't seem to be working in **Chrome**. I have other animations which are working on my page. Is there anything I'm missing or such? Here is my code:

```
@keyframes upToDown {
  0%   { transform: translateY(0); }
  100% { transform: translateY(100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes upToDown {
  0%   { transform: translateY(0); }
  100% { transform: translateY(100%); }
}

@keyframes downToUp {
  0%   { transform: translateY(100%); }
  100% { transform: translateY(0); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes downToUp {
  0%   { transform: translateY(100%); }
  100% { transform: translateY(0); }
}

.hide{
 animation: upToDown 1s forwards;
 -webkit-animation: upToDown 1s forwards;
-webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
.visible{
 animation: downToUp 1s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: downToUp 1s forwards;
-webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

Comment: What's not working? You haven't explained the problem. Please make a jsFiddle with your codes so we can see how it is being used

Comment: According to [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes), Chrome needs a vendor prefix. In other words, `@-webkit-keyframes`. Also, `-moz-` and `-o-` if you want to support last year's Firefox and Opera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't working because you need `-webkit-transform` e.g.:

```
@-webkit-keyframes downToUp {
0%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }
100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
}
```

and

```
@-webkit-keyframes upToDown {
0%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }
}
```